# Grouping elastic seach put commands

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to group 3 commands below into 1 command?

```
PUT /vehicles/_doc/123
{
  "make" : "Honda civic", 
  "color" : "Blue", 
  "from": "Japan",
  "size": "Big",
  "HP" : 250, 
  "milage" : 24000, 
  "price": 19300.97
}

PUT /vehicles/_doc/456
{
  "make" : "honda civic", 
  "color" : "Blue", 
  "from": "Singapore",
  "size": "Big",
  "HP" : 250, 
  "milage" : 24000, 
  "price": 19300.97
}

PUT /vehicles/_doc/789
{
  "make" : "Toyota", 
  "color" : "Blue", 
  "from": "Japan",
  "size": "Big",
  "HP" : 250, 
  "milage" : 24000, 
  "price": 19300.97
}
```

Comment: were u able to resolve issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_bulk` API as @Amit said. Here is a sample also:

```
POST vehicles/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": "123"}}
{"make" : "Honda civic", "color" : "Blue", "from": "Japan",  "size": "Big",  "HP" : 250, "milage" : 24000, "price": 19300.97}
{"index": {"_id": "456"}}
{"make" : "honda civic", "color" : "Blue", "from": "Singapore","size": "Big","HP" : 250, "milage" : 24000, "price": 19300.97}
{"index": {"_id": "789"}}
{"make" : "Toyota", "color" : "Blue", "from": "Japan","size": "Big","HP" : 250, "milage" : 24000, "price": 19300.97}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can use the [Elasticsearch bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) for indexing multiple index request into one request.

You can also specify the id of them, as you are using your own ids(not the Elasticsearch generated one) for your documents.